# How to form a string from 2 values

Tags: python, string, variables, floating-point

Alright, i need to make a string defined as rootString that looks like this:

```
F:0.0
```

The letter F is derived from a previous string, obtained by:

```
root = str(newickString[-1])
```

And the float 0.0 can be as such:

```
rootD = 0.0
```

My question is, how do I combine both variable name and float value with a colon?

Comment: So much for "one obvious way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> string = 'WWF'
>>> num = 0.0
>>> print ("{0}:{1}".format(string[-1],num))
F:0.0
```

On older versions of Python (<2.6) you will need to do:

```
"%s:%s" % (string[-1], num)
```

instead of

```
"{0}:{1}".format(string[-1],num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `+` sign and concatenate them together:

```
>>> old_string = 'oldF'
>>> float_val = 0.0
>>> rootString = old_string[-1] + ':' + str(float_val)
>>> print rootString
F:0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation in Python is quite simple. For most versions of Python, you can write:

```
template = "%s:%f"
root = "F"
rootD = 0.0
result = template % (root, rootD)
# and result is "F:0.0"
```

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

(Note that if you're on a new enough version of Python, you may prefer to use the newer `.format` method on strings -- see http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to combine two values, and print them out.

```
string_value = 'BOF'
float_value = 0.0
print "%s:%s" % (string_value[-1], float_value)
>>F:0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'%s:%0.1f' % (root, rootD)
```

[Read more about string formatting here.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable storing it as a string (or several of the other methods being suggested):

```
rootString = "%s:%s" % (root,rootD)
```

If you are planning on using/changing the value later, it might be better to set up a class like in this example code (plus you can still easily print the string):

```
class rootString:
    def __init__(self,root,rootD):
    self.root = root
    self.rootD = rootD

    def getRoot(self):
    return self.root

    def getRootD(self):
    return self.rootD

    def setRoot(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def setRootD(self, rootD):
        self.rootD = rootD

    def __str__(self):
    return "%s:%s" % (self.root,self.rootD)

if __name__=='__main__': 
    myRootStr = rootString("F",0.0)
    print myRootStr #gives string output you want                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    print myRootStr.getRootD() #but you can still get the float easily                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    myRootStr.setRootD(3.14) #or change it if you need to                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    print myRootStr
```